# WPF how to bind mousedown (command/action) to label

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I can find a lot of command mouse bindings to a button, but what if I want to bind a mousedown event to a binding (MVVM pattern)? I can't find the answer, probably it is something very small I don't see but can someone help me with this?

xaml:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <Grid AllowDrop="True">
     <Rectangle Width="100" Height="50" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" Fill="LightBlue"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding EntityName}" MouseDown="{Binding DoSomething}"/>
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: `<Label Content="{Binding EntityName}">
                <Label.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding Click}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
                </Label.InputBindings>
            </Label>`

Comment: (I supposed you could use Click instead of MouseDown)

Comment: Click = DoSomething?

Comment: yes, of course .

Comment: I asked because my 'DoSomething' isn't called.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use an interaction trigger:

```
<Label Content="{Binding EntityName}" xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoSomething}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Label>
```

Please refer to the following blog post for more information: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/

You will need to add a reference to [System.Windows.Interactivity.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/).

---

Updated version (package mentioned above is not produced by library author):

- Install the Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf NuGet package.
- add xaml reference to http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors

See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/open-sourcing-xaml-behaviors-for-wpf/ for more details

Comment: I think something else is also going wrong because I still got the same error:   System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'A Binding can not be set in the AddMouseDownHandler property of type label. A Binding can only be set in a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.' Strange because all other bindings work.

Comment: @RemcovanHeck no, this option works fine. It seems like you did something wrong

Comment: @RemcovanHeck Maybe we could continue discussion in the [WPF chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf) to understand what's going on?

Comment: Did you really remove `MouseDown="{Binding DoSomething}`?

Comment: @ Foggy Finder, I have to go for today but I will go tomorrow to this chat, thanks.

Comment: @RemcovanHeck great, just ping me when you will have time

Comment: It works fine if I start with this code in a new project, so there is something wrong in my old project I gonne take a look, but for now I'm hepled. Thanks everybody.

Comment: Careful with events I couldn't get this to work then realised the MouseDown event wasn't "bubbling up" so used PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown instead.

Answer (score 6):

The above top rated answer requires access to a dll which is only available if you have blend. (if I understand correct) 
Following some other examples I wrote a behavior which allows you to bind a command (ICommand) property to the UIElement.

Code Below :

```
public static class MouseDownBehavior
{
    #region Dependecy Property
    private static readonly DependencyProperty MouseDownCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
                (
                    "MouseDownCommand",
                    typeof(ICommand),
                    typeof(MouseDownBehavior),
                    new PropertyMetadata(MouseDownCommandPropertyChangedCallBack)
                );
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    public static void SetMouseDownCommand(this UIElement inUIElement, ICommand inCommand)
    {
        inUIElement.SetValue(MouseDownCommandProperty, inCommand);
    }

    private static ICommand GetMouseDownCommand(UIElement inUIElement)
    {
        return (ICommand)inUIElement.GetValue(MouseDownCommandProperty);
    }
    #endregion

    #region CallBack Method
    private static void MouseDownCommandPropertyChangedCallBack(DependencyObject inDependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs inEventArgs)
    {
        UIElement uiElement = inDependencyObject as UIElement;
        if (null == uiElement) return;

        uiElement.MouseDown += (sender, args) =>
        {
            GetMouseDownCommand(uiElement).Execute(args);
            args.Handled = true;
        };
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Implementation :

> Make sure to add the refrence "behavior" to the page/control/window.
>   Example -  xmlns:behavior="clr-namespace:MyWPFApp.Helper.Behavior"

```
<Border behavior:MouseDownBehavior.MouseDownCommand="{Binding UploadImageMouseDownCommand, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Border>
```

Comment: The dlls are now MIT licensed, available at: 
* https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/
* https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/open-sourcing-xaml-behaviors-for-wpf/